# Calling Python functions in C program

Tags: python, c, sha

I would like to call a python function to realize the encryption in SHA256 from a C program. Can someone help me in this work? Or can someone give me an example of calling Python function in C?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain how you would use this function?  Do you need to capture the return value of the function or merely the output?  If it's the latter, then you should look at the `popen` function from stdio.h.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you can't use a library like openssl or mbedtls for C?

Comment: I would like to capture the return value of the function called. I have not a lot of knowledge about the C programming. I think that I could use openssl, can you give me some tips? Sorry for missing information! 
I need an interoperability between Python programs and C programs, so I need to use the same encryption algorithms. I want to encrypt in Python and decrypt in C, and viceversa.

Comment: It seems awfully roundabout to involve Python in this.  There are perfectly good C libraries for computing SHA256 and other hashes.  In fact, using one of these is very likely how whatever Python module you intend to rely upon does it.

Comment: Can you give me some examples for encrpyting with C libaries? Thank you!

Comment: Also, the SHA functions aren't encryption methods.  They're hashing algorithms.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shelling out to a Python script, while it can be made to work, is very hacky and not recommended.  As @JohnBollinger mentioned in the comments, your Python interpreter almost certainly utilizes a C library for its hashing.  Therefore, you'd have a C program call a Python function which calls a C function.  Very roundabout.

You'd be better off using one of the standard TLS libraries available for C, such as openssl and mbedTLS.  Documentation for them is available online (see [here](https://tls.mbed.org/api/)).

Here's an example using mbedTLS:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <mbedtls/md.h>

int hashMe(const unsigned char *data, size_t size) {
    int ret;
    mbedtls_md_context_t ctx;
    unsigned char output[32];

    mbedtls_md_init(&ctx);
    ret=mbedtls_md_setup(
        &ctx,
        mbedtls_md_info_from_type(MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256),
        0 // Indicates that we're doing simple hashing and not an HMAC
    );
    if ( ret != 0 ) {
        return ret;
    }

    mbedtls_md_starts(&ctx);
    mbedtls_md_update(&ctx,data,size); // Call this multiple times for each chunk of data you want to hash.
    mbedtls_md_finish(&ctx,output);
    mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);

    printf("The hash is: ");
    for (unsigned int k=0; k<sizeof(output); k++) {
        printf("%02x ", output[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, instead for AES and DES? Do you have something? Thank you!

Comment: The mbedTLS library implements those as well.  Check out the documentation.

Comment: @Vaahn69, if you find my answer useful, feel free to upvote it.